# How can I parse up to a character, then parse what that matches in Attoparsec?

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

I'm writing a parser for a logfile. One of the lines in the logfile lists the parameters of an HTTP request:

```
  Parameters: {"back"=>"true", "embed_key"=>"12affbbace", "action"=>"index", "ajax"=>"1", "controller"=>"heyzap", "embed"=>"1"}
```

I'm having trouble parsing this with Attoparsec. My basic idea is to parse and discard `Parameters: {`, then keep the text up to `}`. Then I'll parse that text into a list of `(key, value)` tuples. Here's what I've got so far:

```
parseParams :: Parser [(Text, Text)]
parseParams = do
    paramString <- "  Parameters: {" *> takeTill' (== '}')
    let params = splitOn ", " paramString
    -- I'm not sure how to apply parseParamPair to params here

parseParamPair :: Parser (Text, Text)
parseParamPair = do
    key <- parseKeyOrValue
    value <- string "=>" >> parseKeyOrValue
    return (key, value)
    where
        parseKeyOrValue :: Parser Text
        parseKeyOrValue = char '"' >> takeTill' (== '"')

takeTill' :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Text
takeTill' func = takeTill func <* skip func
```

How can I implement this? Should I be using `Data.Attoparsec.Text.sepBy` somehow?

Comment: I assume you mean `Data.Attoparsec.Text.sepBy`?

Comment: Also, Hoogle can't find `takeTill'`, and `takeTill` does not look like something you're really likely to want here.

Comment: Thanks, I did mean `Data.Attoparsec.Text.sepBy`. `takeTill'` is a helper function I made that does `takeTill` + also discards the next character (I added the source for that to the question). My line of thinking is: discard up to the first `{`. Then take the input up to the closing `}` (that's the `takeTill'` part). Then parse that in-between text into the (key, value) pairs.

Comment: Be careful with that strategy.  What if I returned `Parameters: {"data" => "{}"}` ?

Comment: I think I'm protected against having `{}` inside the parameters because those characters need to be escaped in a URL (same with the comma and space), though I'm open to solutions that don't depend on that.

Comment: Oh darn, good call @luqui. I just checked and I found `@` signs inside the URL parameters, so that must mean that `{` `}` `,` and ` ` aren't escaped either well. I'll have to account for that.